# Can I get into trouble stealing?

Tags: the-witcher

I've just started playing The Witcher and while it seems there are ways to alter people's opinion of you (e.g. bribes and signet rings), I can't tell if me taking stuff out of containers in peoples homes will get me in trouble with anyone.

In short: **Does taking other people's stuff have any consequences?**

Answer (score 5):

According to [The Witcher FAQ](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/The_Witcher_FAQ) (in the Looting,Trade section) there are no repercussions.

You won't get in any trouble so you can loot at will.

> ### Looting, Trade
>
> The Witcher does not have a crime system (i.e. stealing), so you can loot without any repercussions.